# Import Sass variables into Javascript with Webpack Encore 1.7.x

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony5, webpack-encore

I just ran compose `recipes:update` on `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` which made me move from `@symfony/webpack-encore` 0.30.x to 1.7.x.

I have a problem with exported SASS variables when trying to import them in JS.

In `assets/styles/config/variables.scss` I have:

```
// ...
$iframe-background-color: $color-lighter;

:export {
  // ...
  iframeBackgroundColor: $iframe-background-color;
}
```

And in `assets/somefile.js`:

```
import styles from './styles/config/variables.scss';

export default () => {
  console.log(styles.iframeBackgroundColor);
}
```

When I try to run yarn dev , I get the following message.

> warn  in ./assets/somefile.js
> 11:46:09 AM
>
> export 'default' (imported as 'styles') was not found in '../styles/config/variables.scss' (module has no exports)

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
   Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('login', './assets/login.js')
    .addEntry('catalog', './assets/catalog.js')
    .addEntry('project-favorite', './assets/project-favorite.js')
    .addStyleEntry('email', './assets/styles/email.scss')

    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
      config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
      config.corejs      = 3;
    })

    .enableSassLoader()
    .enablePostCssLoader()

    .copyFiles({
      from: './assets/images',
      to: Encore.isProduction()
          ? 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          : 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

I tried to add this to my Webpack config, and it then compiles without warnings, however, the style is completely broken.

```
.configureCssLoader((config) => {
  config.modules = true;
})
```

Does anyone know how to do that with Webpack encore 1.7.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me forever to find a suitable solution for my problem, but it was actually quite simple.

I couldn't use the following, since Bootstrap was then exploding.

```js
Encore.configureCssLoader(options => {
  options.modules = true;
});
```

However, I found out that I could use the `?module` suffix on my filename to make Webpack import it as a module.

So the only change I had to make is in `assets/someFile.js` and it goes like this.

```js
import styles from './styles/config/variables.scss?module';

export default () => {
  console.log(styles.iframeBackgroundColor);
}
```

I would've preferred a global config, maybe with a `test` that looks like this:

```js
test: /\.module\.(css|scss|sass)$/
```

But I can live with it for now.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue and found your answer to solve my problem in less than 5 minutes  So thanks for taking forever to find a solution and post them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntaxe  :

***import './styles/config/variables.scss';***

should work four you

Comment: No, I want to be able to use the Sass variable in javascript, not only load the Sass file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not answer the question